# What are “grid hotkeys”?

Tags: starcraft-2

What are “grid hotkeys”? I saw them in the preferences. What are they? How do they work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Basically, it makes it so all units in a building, unit commands, etc. are assigned hotkeys based on their position in the UI. For example, since a Marine is the Top-Left in the Barracks, its hotkey would be Q. Here's a page I found that has a small picture to illustrate: [Grid Hotkeys](http://faqs.ign.com/articles/110/1109259p1.html).

Comment: The link contained some additional useful bits as well, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Grid keys replace the default keybinds by actually mapping the squares of the unit cards to certain buttons on your keyboard.

I don't know the exact commands off hand, but it works something like this:

```
QWERT
ASDFG
ZXCVB
```

These keys become the 3x5 grid of the unit card. Pressing "T" triggers the top rightmost command, usually attack move, no matter the unit, and instead of the usual "A" in the default keybindings.

Answer (score 0):

Grid Hotkeys are a hold over from Starcraft 1.

Default Hotkeys use letters in the building/action command for which reference.  For example, to build a B**u**nker you can use the <kbd>U</kbd> key.

Grid is an alternative style that mimics the layout style of commands on the keyboard. For example the **S**top command is normally bound to the <kbd>S</kbd>; grid instead binds it to the <kbd>W</kbd> key.

Comment: There were a series of mods to sc1 which created grid style hot keys.  They were very popular

Comment: Never saw anything like that in SC1, although TA featured it pretty prominently.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the same functionality at Warcraft III. There were a tiny little piece of software called Keycraft that redefined your key shortcuts to behave like this.

It was a must for me and my friends back in the War3 times :)