# How do I avoid friendly fire in Starcraft 2 single player?

Tags: starcraft-2

I often use the attack-move command on my troops, and in the course of events sometimes click on one of my own and kill him/her instead.

Is there a method to avoid friendly-fire?

I could use the "patrol" command, but I find the P key is too far away for practical use.

Edit: I should mention I am playing on hard difficulty.

Comment: With regards to key distance, have you considered the [grid hotkeys preference](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4701/what-are-grid-hotkeys)? It won't directly solve your actual problem, but it might alleviate the issue of your workaround.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the options, you can adjust your hot keys to the grid pattern.
This will change the hotkeys so you don't have to remember them...

I would suggest to use Attack Move for long distance Attack commands and Patrol for short distance,
both keys will be next to each other which makes it more easier to choose between both.

Other than that, if you are into multi-player too, you might want to consider to learn the habit of attack moving your units through your opponent his army instead of in front.

If you are focus firing units you might want to consider to learn the habit to just (shift) right click on them instead so that when you are surrounding your opponent that you don't accidentally attack your own unit. Right clicking on your own unit cause your army to follow that unit, unless there's another next action in the queue to perform. So accidentally clicks on your own units have no effect when focus firing. Just make sure you don't click the ground instead, as they will walk instead of attack…

The grid pattern is Illustrated in the next picture:

[image]

Comment: +1 for the shift+right-click method. I always forget that in the heat of the battle.

Comment: Grid layout is your best friend \o/.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: your "Patrol" command. If you are assigning your forces to 1-4 number, 'P' key is far away from 1-4 (it is not convenient to click 1-p-2-p-3-p). So you could reassign 'Patrol' command to 'T' key.

In objection to TomWij answer to use 'right click': It is very dangerous to focus fire with right click. Imaging, you are trying to focus your marines on opponent's BC and instead of right-clicking BC you right-click on ground close to the BC... Instead of shooting your marines will go. Usually, you can detect that immediately and correct your order, but... I would spend 1/5 of seconds to press 'a' button and 1/4 more seconds to point mouse on required opponent unit, instead of to 2-3 'right-clicks' on empty ground or own unit.