# What are the keyboard shortcuts (binds) when playing commander?

Tags: natural-selection-2

One of the most important things to being efficient in an RTS is learning the key-binds.  However, I don't see a list of key-binds in Natural Selection 2.  What are they?  Does it differ for alien/marines?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The commander hotkeys are laid out in a [grid system](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4701/what-are-grid-hotkeys) based on their position in the UI. The top row (of tabs) are assigned <kbd>Q</kbd><kbd>W</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>. The two rows of icons below the tabs use <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>C</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.

<kbd>Space</kbd> will take you to the location of the last alert (i.e. structures under attack, marine requesting ammo, etc).

You can select a group of buildings or units and press <kbd>Ctrl+1</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl+5</kbd> to save the group, and <kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>5</kbd> to reselect that group later.

Comment: I know there are binds other than those, though.  What are they all?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I'm trawling through the game's source code to see what I can find...